# How to prove the extrema of that function $y=\sqrt{ax^2 +bx}$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

$$y=\sqrt{ax^2 +bx}$$ It is known that $b \ne 0, a \ne 0$

I need to show that when $a<0$ this function has extrema and when $a > 0$ the function has no extrema

(The extrema is an inner extrema)

I tried many ways but I just cant figure it out :(

Comment: Derive and show there are no/is one root?

Comment: @lolopop tried that but stuck with bunch of a b x so I cant know what happens to the function

Answer (score 1):

Let $g: \mathrm {dom} y \to \mathbb R $ such that $g(x) = ax^2 + bx$ which is differentiable as polynomial with $g'(x) = 2ax + b$. Then $g'(x_0) = 0 \iff x_0 = \frac {-b}{2a} $. However $y>0 \forall x \in \mathrm {dom} \; y  \supseteq \mathrm {dom} \; g'$ so when $a>0$ there is not such an $x_0$ and when $a<0$ there is one.

Comment: Thanks but how did you get that $x_0 = 0$? a little confused by this

Comment: It is $g'(x_0) = 0 \iff 2ax_0 + b = 0 \iff x_0 = -b/(2a)$. That $x_0$ will only equal to 0 iff $b=0$

Comment: Could you elaborate on the last step? How does a>0 imply no such x0?

Answer (score 0):

Consider the parabola $y=ax^2+bx$.  If $a>0$ it is pointing upward, and therefore has no maximum.  It does, however, have a minimum.

If $a<0$ it is pointing downward, so has no minimum.  However for $|x|$ large enough the parabola will dip below the $x$-axis and so the square root stops being real.

Comment: Thanks but I didnt understand why did you say that thing about $|x|$ because I draw some graphs in my notebook and it shows that both cases can have extrema